# TclOO : Create an object without namespace

Tags: tcl

I would like to create an object without namespace.

```
namespace eval myNs {}

proc myNs::my_proc {} {
    for { set i 1} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
        # Create object with specialName
        oo::object create myC${i}
        oo::objdefine myC${i} [list \
            method get {} [list \
                return $i
            ] \
        ]
    }
}

myNs::my_proc

myC1 get
```

> Error : invalid command name "myC1"

It works with `myNs::myC1 get` but I need to set my object with a special name (here `myC`).

Comment: Perhaps `oo::object create ::myC${i}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of an object you are `create`ing does not start with `::`, it is *always* resolved by TclOO with respect to the current namespace prior to creation. If you want the name to be elsewhere than the current namespace, either qualify the name before giving it to `create` or `rename` the object after you created it. Renaming of objects is fully supported.

The standard `create` method (just like the `new` method) returns the fully qualified name of the object it made. *Some metaclasses alter that* (notably ones that make megawidgets).

This, plus the fact that `oo::objdefine` (and `oo::define`) have an alternate syntax for the defining things dynamically case, means we can simplify your code to this:

```bash
proc myNs::my_proc {} {
    for { set i 1} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
        # Create object with specialName
        set obj [uplevel "#0" oo::object create myC$i]
        oo::objdefine $obj method get {} [list return $i]
    }
}
```

I recommend always returning the names of objects you've made (and that persist past the end of the procedure), but you don't actually need to do so.

<sup><sup>`#0` is only quoted for Stack Overflow highlighting reasons.</sup></sup>